# How to increment ID when boll cell is False

Tags: python, dataframe, boolean, primary-key, increment

I have a dataframe with web logs. I created a new temporary column with a bool output and when the row is False, I need to increment ID by 1 and write it to new column. If it's True, then I need write same ID than in previous row.
I tried this:

[image]

but it fill all rows with value 1

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't support ++, but you can do:

Use:

id += 1

instead of:

++id

Comment: it doesn t work... i also tried delete else statement and then it should fills only True rows... but it fills all, also False

Comment: Try data.loc[data['id'] == 'True'] see if that works

Comment: that throw me error "'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed"